Where is the API Reference for Compose Multiplatform's Composable Functions?
I've been trying to locate the API reference for Compose Multiplatform that includes documentation for all composable functions such as Column(), Button(), Image(), Text(), etc., but haven't had any luck. My searches on the official Kotlin documentation and the JetBrains help page for Kotlin Multiplatform development haven't yielded the information I'm looking for. Am I supposed to use the reference of the Jetpack Compose page? Or maybe it's integrated within the IDE (Fleet)?
I feel like I might be missing something obvious and would really appreciate any guidance on where to find this information.

Note to reviewers: this is a request for canonical documentation. It should not be closed as a recommendation request.


The Jetpack Compose documentation is the right place for most of the
API.
For some desktop-specific docs, see
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/README.md

I asked on the official GitHub page and this was the answer. So I guess there is nothing official and we should use Jetpack Compose API reference and the Tutorial page for desktop and web specific things.
